# Automated online judge rejects my solution to math puzzle

Tags: c, loops

Hello guys I have found this question on some website

#### Description

> Spade is a very good detective but he is not so good at math, this time his friend Archer has come to him with a very interesting math problem.  Given two numbers 1 <= N <= 10^9 and 1 <= M <= 100, how many positive numbers with length N have the sum of its digits divisible by M. Archer is very obsessive and does not want numbers with leading zeroes to count. Spade has hired you to solve this problem, now his reputation is in your hands.

#### Input specification

Input contains a single line with two numbers N and M separated by a single space.

#### Output specification

Output a single line with the answer to the problem modulo 1000007.

#### Sample input

```
2 2
```

#### Sample output

```
45
```

#### My Code

Though I am getting the expected output it is not accepting my answer.  Can any one please point out the error in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,m,i,firstnum=1,count=0,lastnum=0,j=0,no=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n>=1) {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        if (m>=1 && m<=100)
        {
            for (i=1;i<n;++i) {
                firstnum*=10;
                ++count;
            }
            for (i=0;i<=count;++i)
                lastnum=lastnum*10+9;

            if (firstnum%m==0)
                ++no;

            for (i=++firstnum;i<=lastnum;++i) {
                j=i;
                int sum=0,r;
                do {
                    r=j%10;
                    sum+=r;
                    j=j/10;
                } while(j);

                if (sum%m==0)
                    ++no;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",no-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"I am getting the expected [output] but it is not accepting my answer "` - What does that even mean?  If you're getting the expected output then what's the problem?  How is this failing?

Comment: I don't know whenever i submit my code it gives the judgement as wrong answer, By the way what is the meaning of modulo 1000007.  ?

Comment: You might get the expected output for the sample case and a few of your own cases, but you need to check for corner cases, cases that might be hard, and especially, for very large numbers ( try a number of range 10^8, and find it's expected output and check it with your output

Comment: @Patel i means take your answer `no-1 `, compute `(no-1) % 1000007`, and report that as the final answer. I.e. change your final print to read: `printf("%d",(no-1) % 1000007)`

Comment: How can i store the value 10^8 in the integer :/

Comment: modulo 1000007 means you have to give the output as the remainder of the answer. That is, if your answer is 10^15, your output should be the remainder when 10^15 is divided by 1000007. This can be achieved by using `( no - 1) % 1000007`).

Comment: Is my logic for the question correct ?

Comment: @Patel did you really mean "numbers with *length* N" or did you mean *magnitude* N?

Comment: 10^8 means 100000000. You need proper big datatypes like `long long int` to store very large values that you might get for `no`

Comment: It mean no with length N and the detective also does not want to count the sum of number with leading zero, To me the logic seems just fine :/

Comment: Your code outputs `0` for the input `100 2`, which I assume is definitely wrong.

Comment: to me it gives the o/p as 1

Comment: @Patel , it gives output `0` for any value for `N` greater than 100, I assume that's definitely wrong ( I gave `100 2` and it gave `1` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve this problem by brute force, which won't work for the sizes involved. A number of length 10^9 can be up to 10^(10^9), which is a huge number that won't fit in an `int` or even a `long long int`. Even if it did, trying to enumerate all numbers of this length one by one would take billions of years.

You need to come up with an approach that doesn't look at the numbers one by one. Just like you can calculate that there are 33 numbers between 1 and 100 that are divisible by 3 without looking at them all, you need to come up with such an approach here. But here it will be harder because you will need to do it without actually calculating the value of 10^n.

Comment: Well u didn't get the question first I need to find the no whose **sum of digits** should be divisible by **M** not the number be divisible by **m**

Comment: @Patel OK, but the cause of the error in your code is still the same: a brute-force algorithm can't work here, and you'll need to come up with a completely different one. Your comment on the other answer suggests that you think your problem is with finding a big enough type, but that won't help you as I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not actually correct.
You have declared "firstnum" variable as int, i.e. it cannot hold value greater than 2^(32-1) (on most of the on line judges). The max value of n in 10^9, hence you are trying to put 10^(10^9) in worst case.

I Hope you have got my point. I you want the approach you can comment below my answer. I don't want to spoil the question for you. :)

Comment: I should then use long long n to store n , firstnum,m and lastnum rt?

Comment: now long long int can store max of 10^19 around, that won't work too

Comment: Well then i cannot use a long double here and long long is the n the largets type which can store the integer. Then don't know hoe to define such  a type which stores such kind of no :/

Comment: The approach of this question is different, you will have to input the number in string and search for the division in string on any search engine. I hope this will help